# What does 'return *this' mean in C++?

Tags: c++, pointers, this

I'm converting a C++ program to C#, but this part has me confused. What does return *this mean?

```
template< EDemoCommands msgType, typename PB_OBJECT_TYPE >
class CDemoMessagePB : public IDemoMessage, public PB_OBJECT_TYPE
{
    (...)
    virtual ::google::protobuf::Message& GetProtoMsg()  { return *this; }
}
```

How would it translate into C#?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`this` means pointer to the object, so `*this` is an object. So you are returning an object ie, `*this` returns a reference to the object.

Answer (score 21):

Watch out that if you try to use `return *this;` on a function whose return type is `Type` and not `Type&`, C++ will try to make a copy of the object and then immediately call the destructor, usually not the intended behaviour.  So the return type should be a reference as in your example.

Comment: I can't reproduce the destructor being called an extra time here https://repl.it/@qaisjp/BusyOutrageousPostscript - maybe because of return value optimisation?

Answer (score 3):

In your particular case, you are returning the reference to 'this', since the return type of the function is a reference (&).

Speaking of the size of returned memory, it is the same as

```
virtual ::google::protobuf::Message* GetProtoMsg()  { return this; }
```

But the usage at call time differs.

At call time, you will call store the return value of the function by something like:

```
Message& m = GetProtoMsg();
```

Comment: It is not "the same" as returning a pointer. It is kind of similar.

Answer (score 2):

You are just returning a reference to the object. `this` is a pointer and you are dereferencing it.

It translates to C# `return this;` in the case that you are not dealing with a primitive.

Answer (score 2):

Using a pointer we can directly access the value stored in the variable which it points to. To do this, we simply have to precede the pointer's identifier with an asterisk (*), which acts as `dereference` operator and that can be literally translated to "**value pointed by**".

Answer (score 1):

Like in C# `this` is an implicit pointer to the object you are currently using.
In your particular case, as you return a reference `&` to the object, you must use `*this` if you want to return the object you are currently working on.
Don't forget that a reference takes the variable itself, or in case of a pointer (`this`), the object pointed to (`*this`), but not the pointer (`this`).