# Why do some class methods return "*this" (object reference of self)?

Tags: c++, this, return-value

There are plenty of codes for explanation on the internet (also specifically here, on stackoverflow) that return `*this`.

For example from post [Copy constructor and = operator overload in C++: is a common function possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1734628/copy-constructor-and-operator-overload-in-c-is-a-common-function-possible) :

```
MyClass& MyClass::operator=(const MyClass& other)
{
    MyClass tmp(other);
    swap(tmp);
    return *this;
}
```

When I write swap as:

```
void MyClass::swap( MyClass &tmp )
{
  // some code modifying *this i.e. copying some array of tmp into array of *this
}
```

Isn't enough setting return value of `operator =` to `void` and avoid returning `*this`?

Comment: How do you think that chaining assignments like `a = b = c` works?

Comment: the "normal" behavior of `operator =` is to return the reference to the result of the operation. You can define it as void but it behaves different to all users expectations. You simple can not write something like `(x=y)++` or any other evaluation which uses the result value. It is important you return the reference to the object not the value only. If you return only the value, the above term will compile but the result is wrong!

Comment: This is called [Method Chaining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining#C.2B.2B). Related: [What does 'return *this' mean in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18162522/514235).

Comment: I would consider this as good introductory interview question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This idiom exists to enable chaining of function calls:

```
int a, b, c;
a = b = c = 0;
```

This works well for `int`s, so there's no point in making it not work for user defined types :)

Similarly for stream operators:

```
std::cout << "Hello, " << name << std::endl;
```

works the same as

```
std::cout << "Hello, ";
std::cout << name;
std::cout << std::endl;
```

Due to the `return *this` idiom, it is possible to chain like the first example.

Answer (score 7):

One of reasons why `*this` is returned to allow assignment chains like `a = b = c;` which is equivalent to `b = c; a = b;`. In general, result of assignment could be used anywhere, e.g. when invoking functions (`f(a = b)`) or in expressions (`a = (b = c * 5) * 10`). Although, in most cases, it just makes code more complicated.

Comment: Also in `if`s ;) `if (a = 5) ...`. Classic bug due to this feature.

Answer (score 1):

you return `*this` when there is a strong sense that you will invoke yet the same action on the object.

for example, `std::basic_string::append` return itself because there is a strong sense that you will want to append yet another string

`str.append("I have ").append(std::to_string(myMoney)).append(" dollars");`

the same goes for the `operator =`

`myObj1 = myObj2 = myObj3`

`swap` doesn't has this strong sense. does the expression `obj.swap(other).swap(rhs)` seems common?